# Trim wont remove the whitespace from string, how to remove elements?

Tags: php, whitespace

Pretty simple solution I am sure but I've tried plenty of solutions to fix this and nothing has helped.

I am trying to strip the whitespace from the start/end of the string, below is my simple code:

```
$equipment_data = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta( $id, 'recipe_equipment', true ) );

$equipment_data2 = trim($equipment_data);
var_dump($equipment_data2);
```

And below is the output, as you can see it has a space at the start and end.

[image]

**EDIT**

After using `urlencode` I can see the following returned:

`%3Cp%3E` at the start of the string (`<p>`)

`%3C%2Fp%3E%0A` at the end of the string (`</p>`)

I've therefore done the following:

```
$equipment_data = trim($equipment_data, "<p>");
$equipment_data = trim($equipment_data, "</p>");
var_dump($equipment_data);
```

However, this gets ride of the space at the start but not the end, potentially something to s with the %0A?

Comment: Use `urlencode` on the value and them dump it, the percent encoding will show you what byte values you are actually dealing with in those positions.

Comment: @04FS it shows at the start of the string is ```%3Cp%3E``` which I assume is <p>, and then at the end it shows ```%3C%2Fp%3E%0A```

Comment: That is a completely wrong use of the second parameter of trim now. This is supposed to be a character _list_, not a fixed text literal it will look for. With `<p>` you are saying, remove any `<`, `p` and `>` that might be at the start/end of the input string, but in no particular order. If your input value was `pppppxxx` to begin with, then this would remove those `p`, and that is not what you actually want to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `preg_replace()` instead of `trim()`

```
$stripped = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $sentence);
```

This code will remove all whitespaces in a string.

Use `preg_replace()` in order to remove tag retained:

```
$stripped = preg_replace('/\<.*?\>/', '', $sentence);
```

(You can search for '<' and '>' or '%3C' and '%3E')

```
$stripped = preg_replace('/\%3C.*?\%3E/', '', $sentence);
```

Comment: Does not work as it isn't whitespace, it seems to be element tags that are retained.

Comment: Are there "<p>" and "</p>"?

Comment: apparently so, I've updated the question with new findings and methods.

Comment: Interesting, I got rid of the whitespace line as I actually need the new line breaks to create the array but removing the <p> tags removes the new line breaks.

Comment: You can remove only "<p></p>" (empty paragraph) using this regex:
`\%3C.*?\%3E\%3C\/.*?\%3E` or this `\<.*?\>\<\/.*?\>`. With this method you'll keep no-empty paragraphs and remove initial ones